# Lenovo T410 running Ubuntu 12.04 won't change brightness

Tags: 12.04, brightness, lenovo

Neither the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> or the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (brighter/dimmer) or using the GUI changes the brightness.

I've looked up some possible solutions, all of which involve editing an obscure text file. None of the other solutions had specifically been for 12.04.

I am hesitant to try editing small text files when the intended version is different than the one I use.

Any threads or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok...read this carefully-

Restart your system, and when you get to the grub menu, dont press enter, but press e (to edit).

This would bring up your menu entry.

Append to the line with starts with **linux** (and looks like linux /boot/linux3.9............ (at the end of this line, leave a space and add) `acpi_backlight=vendor`

After this press F10 to boot.

Now try changing the brightness. If the above solution works, i will tell you how to make it permanent.